# How do I compile F# code with ML compatibility?

Tags: f#

The following F# fragment seems to be valid only if compiled in ML compatibility mode (run it [here](http://rextester.com/MVY61204)):

```
   let i = (1 lxor 5)
```

However I can't compile it in a trivial project in Visual Studio 2012 or using fsc.exe from the command line. I get the error:

> error FS0039: The value or constructor 'lxor' is not defined

Reading the F# spec it says

> Although F# reserves several OCaml keywords for future use, the /mlcompatibility option enables the use of these keywords as identifiers.

It then lists `lxor` as one such operator. So I tried the command line `fsc.exe Program.fs --mlcompatibility` (version 11.0.60610.1), but it stil get the same error.

The documentation for `fsc.exe` seems to indicate that the `mlcompatbility` option only ignores warnings. I didn't see any other relevant options in fsc's documentation or project options in VS to enable compatibility.

All of the other SO questions about F#/ML compatibility seem to be related to which language constructs can be used, but all I'm looking for is how to actually compile in compatibility mode. Do I have to open a specific namespace, reference another assembly, or do something else?

**Update**

I have also tried using the open source compiler `fsharpc` (F# 3.0) on Mono on Ubuntu 13.04. The result is the same as `fsc`.

Comment: I suspect this is a regression as whatever version rextester is using seems to compile fine.  Rextester is using 11.0.50727.1 against your 11.0.60610.  Maybe email `fsbugs@microsoft.com` with a bug report?

Comment: @JohnPalmer I will consider it if no one is able to provide an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `--mlcompatibility` option only turns off warnings, so this looks like a regression.  YOu can verify this by searching the source for all references to `mlcompatibility` here https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/search?q=mlCompatibility&type=Code.

Answer (score 2):

When calling `fsc` (`fsharpc` on non-Windows systems), the compiler options go before the source filenames. So the correct way to call it would be something like:

```
fsc -o:MyProgram.exe --mlcompatibility Program.fs
```

When compiling with Visual Studio, you can go into the project's properties and add `--mlcompatibility` to the `Other flags` box:

[image: Demonstrating how to add the 'mlcompatibility' flag to an F# project]

Comment: I still get the same error. I also tried with `fsharpc`. Same result.

Comment: I tried your exact command line and other permutations to no avail. The order of compiler options does not seem to matter when I have a "normal" F# code.