# How to use command-line options for F# within a .NET Core project?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, f#

I need to use one of the reserved words, sig, in my F# code, in a .NET Core project. As the manual states:

**If you use the --mlcompatibility compiler option, the above keywords are available for use as identifiers**.

*The compilation environment can also be controlled by setting the project properties. For projects targeting .NET Core, the "Other flags" property, ... in .fsproj, is used for specifying extra command-line options.*

In trying to do so, I successfully crashed my project.

How does one put command-line options into the .NET Core project?

TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the part where you had trouble with the *Other flags* - it needs to go into a/the `PropertyGroup`. Here is an example for the default *console* template:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
    <OtherFlags>$(OtherFlags) --mlcompatibility</OtherFlags>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Sadly this will not resolve your main point - using `sig` as an identifier will still be an error (the option did just remove *warnings*)

See the discussion in [How do I compile F# code with ML compatibility?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19625559/how-do-i-compile-f-code-with-ml-compatibility)

---

if you really want to use the identifier you could try this little trick:

```ml
let ``sig`` = "F#"
printfn "Hello world %s" ``sig``
```